# Mac OS X global tint color like iOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstabview

Is there any possible way to set global tint color in OS X. If I want to set brand color on Cocoa control like NSTabView. How cloud I do it?

Comment: The user can set a control tint color in System Settings / General. It's not for "app branding", since it applies to all apps, and you can also only choose between "Blue" and "Graphite".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28617708/1463604

Answer (score 0):

if you need to change it in your app

> class NSAppearance : NSObject, NSCoding Description    An NSAppearance
>   object represents a file that specifies a standard appearance that
>   applies to a subset of UI elements in an app. An app can contain
>   multiple appearance files and—because NSAppearance conforms to
>   NSCoding—you can use Interface Builder to assign UI elements to an
>   appearance.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to do this for an application that wanted to have a very-similar appearance between the Windows and Mac OS X versions (don't judge me - it's what the customers want). What we ended up doing is more-or-less:

1. Create an NSDictionary of brand-approved colors, indexed by what the color is used for (*text colors, background colors, button colors, etc).
2. Add a "user-defined runtime attribute" in the InterfaceBuilder inspector, telling each view which colors to use.
3. Write a category on NSView (and a few other Appkit views) that implements a setter for that attribute, which then calls **-setBackgroundColor:** or whatever other AppKit API you need to change the default colors.
4. Since **-setBackgroundColor:** is only available on views that have a Core Animation layer, we ended up adding code to our NSView property setter to call **-setWantsLayer:YES** on every view which needed a non-default background color.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create an "Appearance file", which you can load to override the visual appearance of AppKit controls. This is not a very well documented process, but see this related StackOverflow question/answer for details.
[How can I make an "appearance file" for NSAppearance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780577/how-can-i-make-an-appearance-file-for-nsappearance)

Comment: Thanks. I got the basic idea about what to do. It`s not easy as iOS.